# How to get value from an checkbox? in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Im trying to get values from a $rootScope object which was binded to the checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="system_history in SystemHistoryResponse.system_history">
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="versionValues[system_history.version]"></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$rootScope.versionValues = {};
```

Output now:

```
versionValues: {"321":true,"322":true}
```

Desired output:

```
versionValues: [321, 322]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just convert the object into an array when I needed it:

```
var a = {"321":true,"322":true};
var b = [];
var i = 0;
for(x in a){ 
    b[i++] = parseInt(x,10);
}
// b === [321,322]
```

Otherwise, you could use the [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) directive(NOTE: I haven't tested this code):

```
html:
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="versionValues[system_history.version]
ng-change="update(system_history.version)"
">
js:
$rootScope.versionValues = {};
$rootScope.versionValuesArray = [];
$rootScope.update(version){
    if($rootScope.versionValues[version]){
        // add version to $rootScope.versionValuesArray
    }else{
        // remove version from $rootScope.versionValuesArray
    }
}
```

But the problem with that is that it takes linear time to insert and remove from an array, which is of the same magnitude as the time to convert the entire object into an array.

Comment: the second method worked just fine!! thank you soo much!